# Escaping spaces in alias in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

This is where the file exists:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Something/something.sqldb
```

This is my command to access the file:

```
connect('~/Library/Application\ Support/Something/something.sqldb')
```

The command does not work because the file, something.sqldb, can not be found. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: that backslash between Application and Support should not be necessary, try removing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use single quotes, you will not escape the space if you use backslash. Use double quotes

```
connect("~/Library/Application\ Support/Something/something.sqldb")
```

If you use Python, you can use [expanduser](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) before putting the string into your `connect` statement

```
connect ( os.path.expanduser("~/........") )
```

Comment: `"` and `'` do the exact same thing in Python. You're thinking of Perl.

Comment: Well, unless the documentation is lying, yes. I haven't read the source for the parser, although `'\ ' is "\ "` returns True.

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood what you are trying to tell me. I know the documentation says they are interchangeable. I am going more in the line of escaping ....like `>>> print "You're able to do this"`
is different from `>>> print 'You're able to do this'`

Comment: @ghostdog74 Escaping works the same with both single and double quotes. But of course if you have one of those inside the string itself then you would have to escape it. But Python gives you the option of just switching the outer quotes instead. It also makes in more international.

Comment: @keith, thanks. like i said, i misunderstood what Wooble is trying to say. If you see my example,  using `"` and `'` is not the same. Hence, the misunderstanding that <`"` and `'` do the exact same thing> quoted by Wooble.

Comment: @ghostdog: True, they do act differently in exactly one way, which is not being closed by the other type of quote. But your first sentence is still incorrect; for escaping a space, which quote character is used is irrelevant. Single quotes won't stop the backslash from escaping the space (although using `r''` or `r""` would)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the space, it is the tilde. Python is not a shell and does not expand special characters in strings. There are functions that can do that. The `os.path.expanduser` and `os.path.expandvars` can expand tildes and `$VAR` portions of the string for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
connect('/home/YOURNAME/Library/Application Support/Something/something.sqldb')
```

I removed the backslash and replaced the tilde with the actual home directory, since Python is not the shell and doesn't expand them the way you were expecting.